# Calculating robust percentiles in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data with a parameter (theta) and the density of the parameter (ghat).
I am attempting to calculate 10th and 90th percentiles.

The problem is that my 90th
percentiles are smaller then the mean. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better
way to get to the percentiles given the data I have?

```r
df <- structure(list(theta = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06,
                         0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17,
                         0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28,
                         0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39,
                         0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5,
                         0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6, 0.61,
                         0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7, 0.71, 0.72,
                         0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83,
                         0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94,
                         0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99), ghat = c(8.0497665821822e-10,
                                                                 1.26230992655857e-06, 8.26438628871083e-05, 0.00145824530878958,
                                                                 0.0124065393081063, 0.0658007731995211, 0.249038975036493, 0.727932651403715,
                                                                 1.72673415548062, 3.43406909516598, 5.85358700869572, 8.68314227655718,
                                                                 11.3284276546002, 13.094173436367, 13.4757519628881, 12.38746868323,
                                                                 10.1900555710108, 7.5111077282492, 4.9909183994075, 3.01639625008116,
                                                                 1.67228183293732, 0.85731428205356, 0.409565196187043, 0.183684664661787,
                                                                 0.0778924799288354, 0.031448806214798, 0.0121711651792063, 0.00454509949213374,
                                                                 0.00164831719139466, 0.000584215715883644, 0.000203629809008254,
                                                                 7.02266909309361e-05, 2.41086667080809e-05, 8.28732776812513e-06,
                                                                 2.86092948666336e-06, 9.90307440023348e-07, 3.43025256131075e-07,
                                                                 1.18650514458439e-07, 4.0894730452215e-08, 1.40139045176172e-08,
                                                                 4.76385534376833e-09, 1.60270281245794e-09, 5.32357991008131e-10,
                                                                 1.74159006347556e-10, 5.597419206501e-11, 1.76283038485334e-11,
                                                                 5.42584004312429e-12, 1.62772510314568e-12, 4.74620239243908e-13,
                                                                 1.3412948371487e-13, 3.66440610180999e-14, 9.66671282421902e-15,
                                                                 2.46018105914716e-15, 6.03455452969417e-16, 1.42510511150036e-16,
                                                                 3.23637808265161e-17, 7.05860980817371e-18, 1.47641726404577e-18,
                                                                 2.95700659895129e-19, 5.66118457054648e-20, 1.03409880677609e-20,
                                                                 1.79856703040568e-21, 2.97184153530068e-22, 4.65359973268091e-23,
                                                                 6.88718470220651e-24, 9.6048794951896e-25, 1.25807242160492e-25,
                                                                 1.54158396409635e-26, 1.7591743130845e-27, 1.86026900777325e-28,
                                                                 1.81301776633084e-29, 1.61875794813682e-30, 1.31532955754031e-31,
                                                                 9.65524286954306e-33, 6.35046336266651e-34, 3.70829126953137e-35,
                                                                 1.90275953781146e-36, 8.47940966417498e-38, 3.23858070076557e-39,
                                                                 1.04413668032609e-40, 2.79241430850164e-42, 6.07033401824646e-44,
                                                                 1.04749686096541e-45, 1.39538655335294e-47, 1.38828675388999e-49,
                                                                 9.91227489676626e-52, 4.83700986305667e-54, 1.51838997861272e-56,
                                                                 2.84052131966389e-59, 2.87016663788723e-62, 1.37611003830011e-65,
                                                                 2.62683062482798e-69, 1.56095716947688e-73, 2.01382058534212e-78,
                                                                 3.22597830727024e-84, 2.51631532528489e-91, 1.65259162698972e-100,
                                                                 1.77718300016021e-113, 1.08471354600224e-135)), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                               -99L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

plot(df)
```

[image]

```r
df$theta[which(df$ghat == max(df$ghat))]      # mle
#> [1] 0.15
df$theta[which(cumsum(df$ghat) >= .1)[1]]     # 10th percentile
#> [1] 0.07
df$theta[which(cumsum(df$ghat) >= .9)[1]]     # 90th percentile
#> [1] 0.08
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think that your calculation of quantiles is incorrect. Just use build in `quantiles(df$ghat,0.1)` for 10% percent quantile. In order to do it by hand, i think that you should order them, cumsum and then divide with overall sum then look up which is bigger than 0.1.

Comment: Fun question to follow along. Carlo's deleted answer was interesting. An edit would have been fair. The graping in it was nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you sum your column `df$ghat`, you'll see that it sums up to `100`. So your 10th quantile should be `>= 10` and your 90th `>= 90`.

After that, it seems like you are basically estimating the quantiles for grouped data. So the way you calculate it is a bit different than the usual way. You can see the formula in *math is fun* in a easily digestable format under "Estimating the Median from Grouped Data": https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html.

I could explain it in my own words about what they talk in the website, but it's so clear in there I don't want to ruin it really. To calculate the 10th and 90th quantile, you can basically convert their formula into respectively:

*10th quantile*

[image: quant10]

*90th quantile*

[image: quant90]

where (in **bold** the "conversion" of the variables in their post to your case):

- `L` is the lower class boundary of the group containing the **quantile**
- `n` is the **sum of the density** (in this case, 100)
- `B` is the cumulative **density** of the groups before the **quantile** group
- `G` is the **density** of the group
- `w` is the group width

Usually in integer groups, they place the lower bound and upper bound of the group in between the elements, which is also doable in your case. In case of the group with `theta = 0.10`, which is after `theta = 0.09` and before `theta = 0.11`, the respective lower bound would be:

[image]

The width `w` mentioned in the formula can also be calculated, based on the boundaries of the group. Considering the previously mentioned example, the lower boundaries of theta `0.10` and `0.11` are respectively `L(0.10) = 0.095` and `L(0.11) = 0.105`, so the width of the first group would be

[image]

Comment: You first statement was my issue. The data is not grouped, but I to appreciate the additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

10% quantile

```
df %>% 
  mutate(cdf=cumsum(ghat)/sum(ghat)) %>%
  filter(cdf <= 10) %>%
  summarise(max(theta))
```

90% quantile

```
df %>% 
  mutate(cdf=cumsum(ghat)/sum(ghat)) %>%
  filter(cdf >= 0.9) %>%
  summarise(min(theta))
```

expected value

```
df %>% 
  summarise(weighted.mean(theta,ghat))
```